# Can an app discover programmatically when it was bought, downloaded, installed, and the price paid?

Tags: ios, app-store, installation

I would like for my app (a single SKU) to provide different initial conditions (e.g. starting in-game currency) depending on if it was installed for free or if the user paid to install it.  The price will be changing from time to time.

Is it possible for the app to look up this information?

Note: this is not for in-app purchases; I know I can look that up using StoreKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are hacks and workarounds that get you part way there but for what you're trying to do you need a fully working solution so it looks like **you can't** which is too bad, I love a good hack :)

Edit: future readers should read the comments for a full discussion.

Comment: But in this case I will have one app, and simply change the price from time to time, depending on promotions, etc.

Comment: Oooooh, so really what you're looking for is how much the user paid for the app, hrm...

Comment: Yes.  Or a reliable way to get the install date, which I could use to look up the information on the server.

Comment: maybe you could change your bundle version when you change the price? (Not the human readable version number, the build number)

Comment: Sounds like he wants to change price independent of the bundle, ie changing it multiple times w/out uploading a new app.

Comment: Seems like this is one of those things you'll have to use CFUUIDCreate  for, stick it in their Keychain with a note or date and query your server with it.

Comment: Right, but if they install but don't launch, and then things change, I want to process that correctly.  They have to launch for me to write any sort of data.  It could very well be that the answer to this question is, "No, you can't do that."  I spent some time searching and couldn't find anything, but its a difficult thing to search for due to the common usage of the keywords (try it!).  So I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Yea looks like there is no sure-fire way to do it I can find either, I read a good work around involving checking the DateModified on a bundle file but that will only tell you when that specific instance of the app was installed, not the date they bought it.

Comment: True, and that can be faked as well.

Comment: Well, if you put "You can't" in your answer, I'll give it the check mark.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Done.  Too bad too, I would probably have used a solution to this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to save the current date at the start of the program, to a variable that is nil until it is first set. Then you have the date when the app is first run. 
You may also check the date of the Documents folder which is created when the App is downloaded.

If you store this date as a user preference variable then it is preserved event when you update the App.
Then you can compare that date to data you get from your server.

Comment: Those options were all eliminated in the comments discussion.